# Nancy website and Nancy wcf host in different projects

Tags: .net, wcf, nancy

I want to have Nancy powered website with `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet` dependency in one VS project and dedicated project for WCF service hosting this web site. The idea behind to test performance and have ability to choose what to use IIS or my own service.

To the references of WCF project I've added web site project. How it might become possible to host Nancy that way?

How to tell Nancy to search Modules not in the current executable, but in DLL attached to it? What conditions should be met? The best guess for now is to make Namespaces agree, but no luck for now. If it helps here is the code I'm using to run Nancy from WCF executable (it's standard):

```cs
class Program
{
    private static readonly Uri BaseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:1234/");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner.LoadAssemblies("Basta.dll");

        using (CreateAndOpenWebServiceHost())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Service is now running on: {0}", BaseUri);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static WebServiceHost CreateAndOpenWebServiceHost()
    {
        var host = new WebServiceHost(
            new NancyWcfGenericService(new Basta.Bootstrapper()),
            BaseUri);

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(NancyWcfGenericService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
        host.Open();

        return host;
    }
}
```

I've used approach from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8139096/1047741) (by calling `AppDomainAssemblyTypeScanner.LoadAssemblies`), but didn't worked, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. When running Nancy as WCF all external resources normally handled in IIS virtual folders become unavailable. This means no templates, no styles, no javascript. Nothing.

So to overcome the issue all additional resources need to be copied to output folder (in Visual Studio properties for each file there is an option for that).