# Getting Cannot access a closed Stream when unit testing Nancy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rest, nancy

I am getting "Cannot access a closed Stream" when unit testing a Nancy web app.

My module is as follow:

```
public class MainModule : NancyModule
{
    public MainModule()
    {
        Get["/{Name}"] = p =>
            {
                var command = this.Bind<MainCommand>();
                return Response.AsJson(command.ExecuteGetMessage());
            };
    }
}
```

And my test is:

```
    [Test]
    public void Should_return_welcome_message()
    {
        // When
        var bootstrapper = new DefaultNancyBootstrapper();
        var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);

        BrowserResponse browserResponse = browser.Get("/", with =>
            {
                with.HttpRequest();
            });

        Console.WriteLine(browserResponse.StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(browserResponse.Body.ToString());

        // Then
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK,browserResponse.StatusCode);
    }
```

**UPDATE:** I am getting StatusCode = NotFound and the exception happens when trying to access browserResponse.Body.

I had a look at the Nancy forum and also here at StackOverflow.
I tried this solution: [Nancy test doesn't find route in other assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139096/nancy-test-doesnt-find-route-in-other-assembly)

but still not working.

When I run the test in debug mode I see that my module is been called but I still cant check the returned value.

What should I do in order to get it working?

Thanks

Ademar

Comment: At which line in the test do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a NotFound response because the route you have defined is different from the route you have called.

You are calling `/` in your test, but the module has a route of `/{Name}`.

The exception is because there is no body with a NotFound response.

Update your test to something like:

```
var bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapper(c=>c.Module<MainModule>());
var browser = new Browser(bootstrapper);
BrowserResponse browserResponse = browser.Get("/ademar", with =>
        {
            with.HttpRequest();
        });
```

*** Updated to include source from the comment ***

Comment: Hi @codeprogression, thanks for the answer. But it didnt fix the problem. I tried that and the result is the same, notfound and the error that i cannot access a closed stream.

Comment: Interesting. The error about the closed stream is expected for a notfoundresponse. Did you add a "hard reference" as in the other question you referenced? You could do `var bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapper(c=>c.Module<MainModule>());` That would look for the module you are testing only.

Comment: I did actually and was still getting the same. Thanks for the replies. I wil probably start another project and check if it will work.

Comment: Hi @codeprogression. It actually worked with var bootstrapper = new ConfigurableBootstrapper(c=>c.Module<MainModule>()); 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Added as the answer, though the real answer is within the comments! Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks @ademar for following up.